# Liquibase Generating a / (slash) before a SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, liquibase

I have a need to generate a / (slash) before a SQL file. The XML code is shown as below :

```
     <sql endDelimiter="\n\n/" dbms="oracle">
        SELECT 1 FROM DUAL;
    </sql>
```

What I need is to have the output as follows: ( notice the / (slash) ):

```
  /
  SELECT 1 from dual;
```

I am using Liquibase 3.5.3

Comment: why you need / before a sql instead of end of sql

Comment: In the change as shown, the slash before the SELECT makes no sense whatsoever. Plus the slash isn't legal SQL - it is only a separator used by the Oracle **tools** it's not part of the SQL syntax.